# Scrapy export dynamic items to csv

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, scrapy

I have spider that scrapes some dinamic fields like this:

```
class exhibitors_spider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "exhibitors"

url = "some url"

def _create_item_class(self, class_name, field_list):
    field_dict = {}
    for field_name in field_list:
        field_dict[field_name] = Field()
    return type(str(class_name), (DictItem,), {'fields': field_dict})

def start_requests(self):
    yield Request(url=self.url, callback=self.parse_page, dont_filter=True)

def parse_page(self, response):
        Contact_Persons = {}
        Contact_Persons_blocks = response.selector.xpath("//h2[contains(text(),'Contact person')]/..//..//div/.//li")
        if Contact_Persons_blocks:
            for i in xrange(1, len(Contact_Persons_blocks) + 1):
                cp_name = Contact_Persons_blocks[i - 1].xpath(".//a[@itemprop='name']/bdi/text()").extract_first()
                if cp_name:
                    cp_name = capwords(cp_name.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    cp_name = 0
                Contact_Persons.update({"Contact_Person_Name_{}".format(i): cp_name})

                cp_title = Contact_Persons_blocks[i - 1].xpath(".//div[@itemprop='jobTitle']/text()").extract_first()
                if cp_title:
                    cp_title = capwords(cp_title.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    cp_title = 0
                Contact_Persons.update({"Contact_Person_Title_{}".format(i): cp_title})

                cp_link = Contact_Persons_blocks[i - 1].xpath(".//a[@class='ngn-mail-link']/@href").extract_first()
                if cp_link:
                    cp_link = self.domain + cp_link
                else:
                    cp_link = 0
                Contact_Persons.update({"Contact_Person_Link{}".format(i): cp_link})

        ExhibitorsItem = self._create_item_class('ExhibitorsItem', Contact_Persons.keys())

        for cp_key in Contact_Persons.keys():
            item[cp_key] = Contact_Persons[cp_key]
        yield item
```

But I do not know in advance how many items I will have, besides on each page there are a different number of items. When I export to CSV, it looks like a Scrapy creates a file with keys from first item. I mean, it writes all values, but if for example the first item has 1 key, then we will have only one key in CSV, and the remaining items will be arranged in the wrong order if they have more keys. How to make Scrapy create a CSV file from an Item with the largest number of keys?

Comment: Hard to know what you're asking. But versions of Python < 3.6 do not have ordered dictionaries.

Comment: Okay, for example, on the first page I have 1 item, on the next 3 items. As a result, I will get a CSV file with 1 key in the header, but with two lines with 1 and 3 values, respectively. I want the resulting CSV header contains all keys.

Comment: But if the first page has 3 items, and the second - 1, then I will get 3 keys in the header. It seems that Scrapy creates a CSV-file with keys of items of first scraped page.

Comment: Delimeter issue?

Comment: Where is the `item` variable defined? Also, consider using Items instead of dictionaries, it might solve your issue: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html